# Error logging-in to the docker hub 'Error response from daemon'

Tags: docker, authentication

used command 'docker login'. It prompted for username that i entered and when supplying the password, i get the following error:
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Not able to login even after several attempts.